# 500 internal server error with .htpasswd/.htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

sorry to ask this again, I know that it's been asked before but I've literally read every discussion for trouble shooting and I'm still having problems

heres my code:

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
AuthUserFile path/index/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "restricted area"
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

whenever I delete the .htaccess from the server the pages run normally but when I re-add the .htaccess I get the internal server error. It's really weird because occasionally an enter your password window comes up even but when I enter the password the window reappears, as if the password was entered incorrectly, and when I reload the page I get the 500 server error. Thanks in advance for the much needed help!!!

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in .htaccess...can you show us this file ?

Comment: What's your error logs say?

Comment: I don't know how to access the error logs.. also that's all that I have in .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

Is probably what's causing you the error. The `AllowOverride` directive tells apache **what is allowed to be used in things like htaccess files**. So obviously, it's not something you can set *in your htaccess file*. `AllowOverride` needs to be in the server or vhost config, and the `AuthConfig` part of it tells apache that you can have auth directives (like AuthType, AuthName, etc) in an htaccess file.

Comment: I added the line because I saw that as an answer somewhere, and without the line the code still doesn't work- do you know how to add the allowoverride to the server or to see if it's already there?

Comment: @user3015721 You need to add it to your vhost or server config. Depending on your setup or your OS/linux distro, it could be done in a number of different places. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles

Comment: what if there is no file with this etc/apache2/sites-available/default name?

Comment: @user3015721 there's a ton of places it could be, google for your os and/or your linux distribution.